# Code or Logic to find number of char appearances in a string composed of consecutive numbers

Tags: vba, math, logic

I am struggling with this exercise where I have to find a number (y) so that when counting the times (nr) the value "1" appears in a string (x) composed of all the consecutive numbers starting from 1 to y, the following conditions are met: nr=y and nr is divisible by 10.

example:

x (string with consecutive from 1 to 12)= 123456789101112

y (the number) = 12

nr (times of "1" appearances) = 5

so i need to find the situation where nr=y and y mod 10 = 0

I've tried creating a vba sub to do this, but it takes forever and cannot seem to find a suitable result:

```
Sub abc2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim i As Double
Dim y As Double
Dim nr As Double
Dim x As String
x = 1
y = 1

    For i = 1 To 500001


        x = x & (y + 1)
        y = y + 1

        nr = Len(x) - Len(Replace(x, "1", ""))


        If nr = y And nr Mod 10 = 0 Then
            Range("E1") = y
            GoTo out
        End If

Next i

out:
    Range("A1") = x
    Range("B1") = y
    Range("C1") = nr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate some suggestions. Maybe it can be solved in some other ingenious way.
Thank you!

Comment: 199990 is the first one I found with a brute-force script O(n^2), adding 10 to y every time. You could definitely do this in linear time, though, by counting how many `1`s you're adding in each step.

Comment: this is the result my code finally returned after !1.5 hours of running..can you share your full code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python:

```
x = ''
y = 0

####################################
# BRUTE FORCE, FINDS ANSWER 199990 #
####################################
#for iteration in range(100000):
#    for index in range(10):
#        y+=1
#        x+=str(y)
#    if (y == x.count('1')):
#        print 'Found: ' + str(y) + ': ' + x
####################################

# More elegantly and efficiently, just track how many '1's we've added in each step
ones = 0
for iteration in range(100000):
    x = ''
    for index in range(10):
        y += 1
        x += str(y)
    ones += x.count('1')
    if (y == ones):
        print 'Found: ' + str(y)
```

The commented-out solution takes about 2 minutes to execute. The second solution finishes in .46 seconds.